# Order by count same values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
ID |  Name  |  Group   

1    Mary      1    

2    Rose      1

3    Rose      2

4    Bob       2

5    Bob       2
```

I'd like to order them by Group, then by count(Name) and then rand()
So with this result:

```
ID |  Name  |  Group   

4    Bob       2

5    Bob       2

3    Rose      2

2    Rose      1

1    Mary      1
```

I wrote this query, but if I add count(Name) between group and rand, it gives me a bad result

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Group DESC, RAND();
```

Comment: `GROUP` is a reserved word. You might need to enclose that identifier in backticks.

Comment: @stickybit I just used it here as an example, I have different column names on my db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
INNER JOIN (SELECT Name, count(*) AS countName FROM table GROUP BY Name) AS t1 ON t.Name = t1.Name
ORDER BY Group DESC, countName DESC, RAND();
```

Comment: @gordon-linoff answer "In earlier versions, you can use a subquery" work too, check it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions in the `order by`:

```
order by count(*) over (partition by name) desc,
         name
```

Note:  This doesn't randomize by name.  If you really want that:

```
order by count(*) over (partition by name) desc,
         min(rand()) over (partition by name),
         name
```

In earlier versions, you can use a subquery:

```
order by (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.name = t.name) desc,
         name
```

Comment: I've never used those functions, but I just tried your solution and  I receive syntax error: SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Group DESC, count(*) over (partition by name), RAND()

Comment: `GROUP` is a SQL keyword.  You should really rename the column.  But if you can't, then escape the name.

Comment: Thanks, but I just used it here to show an example. My column has a different name on db, there should be another error on that query

Comment: @Erry215 . . . Here is an illustration that the *syntax* works fine:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=87b533f888ec3895be10fee372931d32.

Comment: It does not work in MySQL less than 8.0 (Before MySQL 8.0 you can't use window functions)

Comment: @nachospiu oh.. That's why. My host is using 5.7, are there any other solutions?